# Flutter GetX Controller Not Getting Disposed Automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I'm Using GetX As A State Management Tool and it was very helpful,
but I got a bug when navigating to a page and going back the page controller doesn't get disposed and the `onClose()` method doesn't get called so I can't dispose the controller manually using `Get.delete<Controller>()`.
and I checked answers here pointing out to initialize the controller in the `build()` method and it also didn't work.

I'm using GetX `^4.6.5`

Navigating with Named Navigation i.e `Get.toNamed('/page1 )`

**UPDATE**

code snippet
the Page

```
class UnitsList extends StatelessWidget {

  const UnitsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const horizontalPadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10);
    final UnitsListController controller = Get.put(UnitsListController());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Units List'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: horizontalPadding,
        child:GetX<UnitsListController>(
          builder: (_)=>controller.isBusy.value
              ?const AppCircularIndicator()
              : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  GetBuilder<UnitsListController>(
                    builder:(_)=> ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: controller.unitsList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        var item = controller.unitsList[index];                    
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            controller.selectedUnit = item;
                            print('${controller.selectedUnit!.rent}');
                            controller.onUnitTap();
                          },
                          child:  AppUnitCard(
                           //...
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
          ),
        )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the Controller

```
class UnitsListController extends GetxController {
  final _className = 'Units List Controller';

  List<Unit> unitsList = [];

  String? _requestType;

  RxBool isBusy = false.obs;
  Unit? selectedUnit;

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    log('onInit', name: _className);

    isBusy.value = true;

    //Some APIs Calls and handling data
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    isBusy.value = false;
    log('onReady', name: _className);
    super.onReady();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    log('onClose', name: _className);
    super.onClose();
  }

  void onUnitTap() {
    log('_requestType : $_requestType', name: _className);
    if(selectedUnit == null ||_requestType==null){
      return;
    }
    

      var selectedUnitData = {NavigationParams.unit: selectedUnit!.toJson()};
    
      if (_requestType == NotificationsStrings.evacuation) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.evacuationRequestPage,
            arguments: selectedUnitData);
      } else if (_requestType == NotificationsStrings.maintenance) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.maintenanceRequestPage,
            arguments: selectedUnitData);
      } else if (_requestType == NotificationsStrings.renting) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.paymentServicesList, arguments: selectedUnitData);
      } else if (_requestType == NavigationParams.searchUnitTapRequest) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.unitDetailsPage,
            arguments: selectedUnitData,
            parameters: {
              NavigationParams.unitDetailsKey: NavigationParams.unitDetailsRent
            });
      }
      else if (_requestType == NavigationParams.customerViewUnitTapRequest) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.unitDetailsPage,
            arguments: selectedUnitData,
            );
      }
      else if (_requestType == NavigationParams.ownerInvitingSpUnitTapRequest) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.servicesProvidersList,
            arguments: selectedUnitData);
      }
      else if (_requestType == NavigationParams.ownerViewUnitTapRequest ||
          _requestType == NavigationParams.ownerViewEmptyUnitTapRequest ||
          _requestType == NavigationParams.ownerViewOccupiedUnitTapRequest) {
        Get.toNamed(AppRoutes.unitDetailsPage,
            arguments: selectedUnitData,
            parameters: {
              NavigationParams.unitDetailsKey: NavigationParams.unitDetailsEdit
            });
      }  
  }  
}
```

so please any help would be appreciated

Comment: Kindly tell me whether you are trying to navigate to a new screen from bottom navigation bar or on button click. If possible, share the code

Comment: @JabeedAhmed
it's onTap method in a (GestureDetector) Widget 
and mostly Buttons and i'm using named navigation using the registered named page => GetPage(name: pageName)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz
well, it's too late now I've written a whole project using GetX
maybe I can migrate to another State Management in future Releases .
if there anything i can do please mention it.

Comment: @AbanoubRefaat Possible to share the controller code? and also check if you have wrapped parent widget of that screen with GetBuilder.

Comment: @JabeedAhmed
i just did.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz 
btw I tired to make a demo using Provider but I've faced the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've solved my problem with a work around approach, so don't judge me if that's not a best practice or a poor solution.

lets consider that i have a two pages `Page1(),Page2()` and their controllers
`Page1Controller(),Page2Controller()`.
and i wanted to go back and forth and when i revisit Page2() i wanted it's controller to be re-Initialized.

so what i did simply is when i'm at `Page1()` and before i call `Get.to(Page2())`
i make sure that the `Page2Controller()` is already deleted so i use `Get.delete<Page2Controller>();`
and to test this you can see the loge `Page2Controller() onInit()`.

so the full solution code is like that:

Page1Controller Navigation:

```
Get.delete<Page2Controller>();
 Get.to(Page2());
```

and Page2Controller :

```
import 'dart:developer';

class Page2Controller extends GetxController {
final _className='Page 2 Controller';

 @override
  void onInit() async{
log('onInit',name:_className);
}
}
```

you will find out that with this approach the Page2Controller will get Re-Initialized every time you go to Page2

Answer (score 0):

@AbanoubRefaat the Controller is bond to the named route, it will get disposed when the route popped.

In your case, you are pushing the page on top of another page. The controller won't be disposed because page A is still there.
When you pop pageB, Page2Controller will be disposed.
If you replace pageA with pageB by calling Get.offNamed, PageAController will be disposed.

```
// Going to a page
Get.toNamed(AppLinks.DASHBOARD);
// Move back one page only
Get.offNamed(AppLinks.LOGIN);

// Going back all route/pages until LOGIN page you can even pass a predicate/ condition to pop until that condition passes
Get.offAllNamed(AppLinks.LOGIN);


// Pop the current route and to the defined route.
Get.offAllAndToNamed(AppLinks.ORDERS);
```

Comment: no sir the problem with my code is that the controller2 does not get disposed nor the onClose() gets called when i navigate back to Page1

Comment: to be more clear about the issue it doesn't get disposed the 1st time meaning that if i did navigate to page 2 for the second time and navigate back the controller will get disposed but the 1st time it wont

Comment: Is this code on github? Possible to share there? I will debug and check what exactly the issue is

Comment: i Already gave you a snippet of my code 
and u dont have to get my code just create a new project use the same get version as me => ^4.6.5 and try to navigate back and forth you will find the issue